# When hovering on titles their container shift on IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

When hovering on titles their container shift on IE9

Check it out on the link 
http://www.kbh.org.il/

It also happened on IE7.

This is a Joomla website. Sorry if the code is bad.

Another issue that might be related is a strange behavior when selecting text. The selection is not accurate.

Comment: The problem isn't in there in Safari, and your website isn't in English or Spanish, so I can't really help you :(

Comment: Mark Robinson, don't forget the HTML and CSS source is in English, as well as errors shown in the browsers console. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PHP` has perhaps done something unexpected, as your HTML page is rendered in `quirks mode` due to some residue content seen at the very top of the page, prior to the `DOCTYPE`:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width=1 height=1 style="visibility: hidden"></iframe><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

To be sure, I did not see any shifting of containers in **IE8** for XP, but I did see the abnormal text selection when that was tried. Forcing the webpage to render in **IE8 Standard Mode** allowed the text selection to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I investigated about this iframe tag and found out that the site was infected by malware. I recovered the original php and it fixed the problem. The joomla installation was upgraded so I hope it won't happen again.